# IOS can read Media Fragments with Blob

Tags: html

I am trying to use media fragments to give a thumbnail

Here is my html

```html
<video preload="auto" controls="controls">
   <source data-v-3e35226f="" src="blob:http://localhost:8080/0dc9b1e1-5a6c-48c9-9618-3c8f1826dbfd#t=0.001" type="video/mp4">
   <source data-v-3e35226f="" src="blob:http://localhost:8080/0dc9b1e1-5a6c-48c9-9618-3c8f1826dbfd#t=0.001" type="video/quicktime">
</video>
```

It works in Andriod device, while IOS cannot read the file.

I also tested IOS can use media fragment with normal url.

how can I fix it while keep using blob url as video soure?

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in webkit that it cannot handle blob URL with fragment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219361

In my case, I set the start time right after it loads metadata:

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',() => {
  this.currentTime = 0.1;
});
```

In the video html tag, I use `preload="metadata"` instead.

Comment: Works, preload="metadata" is the key here, does not work without it.